# How do I edit colum in SharePoint Online using JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, column

Hope you're well;

What is javaScript code to add on SharePoint list for showing a few lines of text per row so they all the same size where reams of text have been written this is via scroll or expand arrow can it be applied to all views.

This is code I use:

```
<script>


 if(typeof jQuery=='undefined'){ 
 var jQPath = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js'
 document.write('<script src="',jQPath,'"><\/script>'); 
 } </script><style>

.expandText {
  HEIGHT: auto
 }
 .collapseText {
  OVERFLOW: hidden; HEIGHT: 18px
 }</style><script>


 function ExpGroupRenderData(htmlToRender, groupName, isLoaded) { 
 $("#tbod"+groupName+"_").attr("isloaded",isLoaded) 
 .html(htmlToRender) 
 .show("fast",collapseText("#tbod"+groupName+"_")); 
 } 
 function collapseText(group){ 
 if (!group) group = "#MSO_ContentTable"; 
 var html = "<img alt='collapseText' style='cursor:pointer;' src='/_layouts/images/menudark.gif'/>"; 
 $(group+" td.ms-vb2>div").each(function(i,e){ 
 $(e).css({display:"inline-block"}); 
 if (e.clientHeight > 35){ 
 $(e).toggleClass("collapseText") 
 .prepend(html); 
 } 
 }); 
 $(group+" img[alt='collapseText']").click(function(event){ 
 $(event.target).parent().toggleClass("collapseText"); 
 }); 
 } 
 $(function() { 
 collapseText(); 
 }); 

</script>
```

However it works on SP 2010 using content editor web part on a list. But on SP Onnline it don't work.

```
<style type="text/css">
.collapseText {
    OVERFLOW: hidden; 
    HEIGHT: 18px
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
    collapseText(); 
}); 

function collapseText(){     
    var html = "<img alt='collapseText' style='cursor:pointer;' src='/_layouts/images/menudark.gif'/>"; 
    $(".ms-listviewtable td.ms-vb2>div").each(function(i,e){ 
        $(e).css({display:"inline-block"}); 
        if (e.clientHeight > 35){ 
            $(e).toggleClass("collapseText").prepend(html); 
        } 
    }); 
    $(".ms-listviewtable img[alt='collapseText']").click(function(event){ 
        $(event.target).parent().toggleClass("collapseText"); 
    }); 
} 
</script>
```

I have tried this code it works in SP2010 but not SP Online.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, 

Hope you're well;

it don't seem to be working. 








I have tried the following:
•content editor web part 
•Scrpit editor web part 
•I saved file as JS and put into site assets and link to content      editor web part


The code works on SP 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by testing of this jQuery selector is still valid.

```
$(".ms-listviewtable td.ms-vb2>div")
```

SharePoint online in classic mode is based on SharePoint 2013 and not SharePoint 2010. I'm reasonably sure that there are HTML and css class changes between these products.

This is the exact reason why you should be careful with UI customizations. They tend to be break with updates.

Comment: The code did not work.

Comment: Then you need to inspect your HTML and figure out the correct selector to make this work. Unfortunately I don't have a complete and ready solution. If you don't have any jQuery / javascript or SharePoint experience, this will be hard to figure out.

Comment: How come the code works in SP 2010